# I want to make tabs below custom action bar using tabhost on the activity where I used custom toolbar as action bar?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am the android developer (freshers).
Here is my java code. where I have tried TabSpec.addTab(.......) but it gives me error of nullpointerexception. plz let me know what should I do?  please provide me the code for tabhost with xml and java...thank you.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }   

}
```

Is this the error where I use supportactionbar methods?
please help me I want to use these tabs with the listview and searchview..
thank you.

Comment: put your XML also i doubt in this line `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);` `R.id.app_bar` is app bar not toolbar

Comment: can you also add your manifest and styles?

Comment: The problem is solved by using fragments with the tab host. thank you.